# C# SQL filter for a pair of values?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm working with a data table that has some rows in it copied over as kind of a backup. I'm trying to filter out data that's been copied but I'm having some trouble because I need to filter on a pair of columns. Each row has a name and a date, a flag for if it's a copy or a few other things (has more then just two values, but these are the ones I'm interested in) and some other information. I'm trying to get all the rows that do not appear as backups, so for example:

```
ABC 1/1/2001 dataSet ...     |     ABC 1/1/2001 backupSet ...
DEF 2/2/2002 dataSet ...     |     DEF 2/2/2002 backupSet ...
GHI 3/3/2003 dataSet ...     |     ABC 4/4/2004 backupSet ...
ABC 4/4/2004 dataSet ...     |     
DEF 5/5/2005 dataSet ...     |     
ABC 6/6/2006 dataSet ...     |
```

Would result in:

```
GHI 3/3/2003 dataSet ...
DEF 5/5/2005 dataSet ...
ABC 6/6/2006 dataSet ...
```

I can filter on one column, but I don't know how do both simultaneously.

```
var result = from a in db.table
where a.type == "dataSet"
let backupData = (from b in db.table where b.type == "backupSet" select b.name)
where !backupData.Contains(a.type)
select new DataObject
{
     ...
};
```

Is as far as I got.

I'm also trying to keep it to just one query since the result set could potentially be quite large, so I didn't want to just create a pair of collections in memory and then try and filter them out. Is that possible? Still a bit inexperienced at SQL, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338(v=vs.110).aspx) (with `!`):

```
var result = 
    from a in db.table
    where a.type == "dataSet"
        && !db.table.Any(b => b.type == "backupSet"
            && b.name == a.name && b.date == a.date)
    select new DataObject
    {
         ...
    };
```

or (looking a bit more complicated, but in general more efficient) [antijoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) (implemented as [left outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) with `null` right side):

```
var result = 
    from a in db.table.Where(x => x.type == "dataSet")
    join b in db.table.Where(x => x.type == "backupSet")
        on new { a.name, a.date } equals new { b.name, b.date } into bGroup
    from b in bGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where b == null
    select new DataObject
    {
         ...
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do (and what you can do), you may want to use `group by`, assuming `name` is the key to link backupSet and dataSet together:

```
var result = db.Table
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.name, x.type }) // Composite key
    .Select(g => new {
        Name = g.Key.name, // ABC, DEF, etc
        Type = g.Key.type, // "backupSet", "dataSet"
        LastRecord = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.date).FirstOrDefault() // Last record for either backupSet or dataSet
    })
    .ToList() // Materialize... query can be very complex
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => new {
        Name = g.Key,
        LastBackupSet = g.First(x => x.Type == "backupSet").LastRecord,
        LastDataSet = g.First(x => x.Type == "dataSet").LastRecord
    })
    .ToList();
```

Be careful though, in the last expression g.First can throw *Sequence contains no elements* and `.LastRecord` can throw *Object reference not set to an instance of an object*